# How to use setQ() method in google calendar api v3 java

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

Can someone give me an example on how to use the setQ() method on google calendar v3 api for calendar events in Java? I try the setQ() method in google drive and it's worked fine, so I want to know how to do the same thing in google calendar events.

So for example, I have an event description in my 'primary' calendar that contains the word 'event test' and I want to retrieve all events in this 'primary' calendar that has its description contains the word 'event test'. Because I want to avoid looping all the hundreds or thousands of events in my calendar to find a specific event.

Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to read that this is only feature free text search, so it doesn't look exactly like in Drive, so I can only use the 'event test' to search it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Events feed = client.events().list("calendarId").setQ("search text").execute();

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the answer. Actually, the setQ in Drive is better than in calendar events. I hope they will implement that as well in calendar api.

Comment: I have a different question regarding setQ though... is it possible to invert the search in some way, so that it returns events that do NOT match the search text?  Or is the only way to achieve this by manually filtering results after getting the full list?

Comment: The setQ in Google Drive API can do that.